# How to get value of selected element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multi level buttons such that I select one of button in level 1 and I want to show button in next level.

Now, I want to get value of button that I selected with JavaScript code. Below is my code. I bring my code for show multi level buttons:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var menuArray = ['0'];

$(function () {
    $('.showButton').click(function () {
        //get target div to show
        var targetID = $(this).attr('target');
        
        //hide all divs
        $('.targetDiv').hide();
        
        //show all menu items in chain
        var found = false;
        
        //get containing div target number
        var current = $(this).parent().attr('id').toString().charAt(3);
        var length = menuArray.length;
        
        //remove elements of array lower than clicked button
        for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
            //check if next menu item is a button just pressed and never delete root menu (elem == 0)
            if(menuArray[0] == current || menuArray[0] == 0) {
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
                found = true;
            }
            //hide div if no longer in menu structure and remove from menuArray[0]
            if(!found) {
                $('#div' + menuArray[0]).hide();
                menuArray.shift();
            }
        };
        
        //add new target to beginning of array
        menuArray.unshift(targetID);
        
        //show each element in the menu structure
        menuArray.forEach(function(elem, index) {
            if(index != 0) {
                $('#div' + elem).show();
            }
        });
        
        //get div of target to show sliding effect
        var targetDiv = $('#div' + menuArray[0]);
        
        //show the div as the last element on the page
        targetDiv.insertAfter('#div' + menuArray[1]);
        
        //slide out last div
        targetDiv.show('slide');
  
    });
  
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="div0" class="buttons">
    <div class="showButton" target="1">A_Level1</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="1">B_Level1</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="1">C_Level1</div>
</div>

<!-- div1 Branch -->
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
    <div class="showButton" target="6">A_Level2</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="6">B_Level2</div>
 <div class="showButton" target="6">C_Level2</div>
</div>


<div id="div6" class="targetDiv">
    <div class="showButton" target="7">A_Level3</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="8">B_Level3</div>
 <div class="showButton" target="9">C_Level3</div>
</div>
```

What shall I do?

Comment: if I am reading this correctly, you want to get the value of the `target` attribute, right?

Comment: yes I want to get value of selected button, such as on of them "A_level1, B_level1, C_level1", and in next level on of them "A_level2,B_level2,C_level3",.....

Comment: For future viewers of this page / comments, the objective was not to get the target attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your anonymous function, inside `$('.showButton').click(function () {` you can access the value with `$(this).text();` (or `$(this).html();` if you need any html elements with it).

See the following example using this method::

```js
$('.showButton').click(function(){
  $('#log').val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.showButton{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div0" class="buttons">
    <div class="showButton" target="1">A_Level1</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="1">B_Level1</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="1">C_Level1</div>
</div>

<!-- div1 Branch -->
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
    <div class="showButton" target="6">A_Level2</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="6">B_Level2</div>
 <div class="showButton" target="6">C_Level2</div>
</div>


<div id="div6" class="targetDiv">
    <div class="showButton" target="7">A_Level3</div>
    <div class="showButton" target="8">B_Level3</div>
 <div class="showButton" target="9">C_Level3</div>
</div>
<hr>
<textarea id='log'></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you @Jesse, I think my javascript's code is not good. I want to show  button of level 1 first, after choose on of them it shows button of level 2 and etc. Given that which on I choose, I have a query in data base according selected buttons.
please help me.